# roslaunch external program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run a non-ros program from a roslaunch file? For example, I would like to run the system installed version of Gazebo.

I looked in the roslaunch documentation, and couldn't find a solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54640/roslaunch-external-program/) by [natekoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/2334/natekoenig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK it's not possible. Depending on how much you need it, you could create a ROS package with one bash script `sytem_run.sh` or similar, that just runs whatever binary + args is passed as params.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nate, the suggested method was to wrap a system call.

See this node: 
http://www.ros.org/wiki/webots_run  
for an example of running an executable from a ROS package.

Two useful behaviours are: 
**1.** This node launches with required="true" and the source code doesn't ros::spin. The result is that if you launched everything from one launch file, when you close the simulator, it will drop back to console. (this is good once the system is complete) 
**2.** Alternatively, you can start roscore in 1 terminal, this node to launch the simulator in a 2nd terminal, then in the 3rd terminal you can keep re-launching your controller nodes while you debug them, without taking down the simulator front-end each time.

Refs:  
http://answers.ros.org/question/33772/run-shell-command-from-launch-script/  
http://answers.ros.org/question/51474/can-i-run-a-bash-script-using-roslaunch/

p.s. Any idea how long before ROS Fuerte users will be able to seamlessly swap to Gazebo stand-alone? ;-) (eg. if currently using the PR2 Controller Manager joint controllers)

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2